# Android App - mediaplayer always available

Tags: android, android-activity, media-player

this is my first post on stack overflow so hoping you can help.

We are developing an Android App, that requires an audio player to always be available, no matter what activity you are on. Ideally, we want this to be a "pop up" style player that is accessible when you tap the screen or tab an always visible button (e.g. on the action bar). However, the player needs to overlay the activity you are on, and continue playing the audio as you move between activities and (ideally) multi task within your device.

I have looked into various options for this, and wonder if a service is the best way to go. The other option I am considering is a transarent activity. But I am open to suggestions!

Can anyone offer any guidance? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that service, playing the tracks is the best way to go.

For the player visual interface, you should have one view, which will be included wherever you need it.
When you open this view, you will get the information from the service (what track are you on, where exactly in the track) and initialize with those results.

At least this is my suggestion approach to the task. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Danail, I have started to go down the Service route with a separate view for the UI and seems to be going ok so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried considering making it an android widget? It remains on the home screen and user can play music and get back to other tasks. 
But not sure if it will meet your overlay criteria(Which I quite didn't understand.. :))

Answer (score 0):

Check out Androids [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)-Class. This should prevent you with all nessesary playback functions. On how to create your player-controll-interface on Androids Action-Bar, check [Googles Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). But note that the ActionBar is available since Android 3.0, not in previous version!